# "PySAL"python qgis says --- is not recognised as an internal or external command

Tags: qgis, pysal

while loading **hotspot analysis**, it gives following 2 error
1. Couldn't load plugin 'HotspotAnalysis' due to an error when calling its classFactory() method 
2. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'libpysal'

then i tried to add **pysal lib** using many ways as per community search/suggestion but unable to do. it gives " not recognised as an internal or external command" error.

I am using qgis 3.10.

Comment: How are you loading hotspot analysis? How did you try to add pysal?

Comment: i installed hotspot analysis through manage & install plugin option. And tried to add pysal as per procedure mentioned in 1. https://planet.qgis.org/planet/tag/pysal/                    2. https://github.com/danioxoli/HotSpotAnalysis_Plugin. but failed

Comment: Are you on Windows? "But failed" what failed? Which part? Did you try installing using the method in 2? What was the error message? We cannot see your workflow, can you be a but more descriptive in your question.

Comment: yeah sir, i am using windows. i have installed pysal,pandas,scipy & then hotspot analysis plugin as per method "https://github.com/danioxoli/HotSpotAnalysis_Plugin". but when i load hot spot plugin----the complete pop up message is pasted as such in next comment boxes serially

Comment: Please edit your question instead of posting multiple comments.